# Create core dumps on Cygwin

Tags: c, debugging, cygwin, coredump

I need to enable core dumps in cygwin. I have used `ulimit -c unlimited` but when the program I want to debug crashes, there still is no coredump in the directory. Is this actually the correct way to enable core dumps and where can I find the dump then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be working.  What shell are you using?

Don't forget that the dump is not named "core" ... rather on a Windows machine with Cygwin it will likely be named something like "mybadprog.exe.stackdump"

Comment: As I recall Cygwin stackdump files contain much less information than Unix/Linux core dump files.

Comment: Indeed, the content of the stackdump seems to be essentially a backtrace.